# C - WinAPI - send message to thread and wait for it

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, process, message

I want to send a message in WinAPI to window, created in other thread and then wait for process this message.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SendMessage()` to send a message to a window.

`SendMessage()` blocks the calling thread until the message had been delivered **and** processed by the target window's message dispatcher.

From [`SendMessage()`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

Comment: This method could create deadlock... Maybe it is safer to use `PostMessage` instead and communicate with the GUI with custom messages... Just a thought...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Perhaps [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx) might be preferable?   Given what the OP asked for, though, I'd go with straight `SendMessage`.

Comment: @EricBrown: Creating windows *in thread function* is risky. Main thread should be **the only one owning the GUI**, and thread function should **not** create windows / directly access GUI elements. When thread and GUI needs to communicate they usually **post ( not send )** custom messages which prevents deadlocks. Also other ways of synchronization are used like `Event Objects`, `Mutexes`, `Critical sections` etc. Still, I am not that experienced and maybe am missing something. OPs question is not that clear, but I assume he will get burned with his approach...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff message-only hwnds are very handy for intra-app cross-thread communications.

Comment: @EricBrown: Didn't know that. It seems tricky to me, that is why I would shy away from it. Maybe I will try it in my spare time just to see how it goes ( it might prove to be very handy ). Best regards.